# TCL: Duda con split

Tags: tcl

Tengo poca experiencia en lenguaje TCL, pero estoy utilizando la función split y no me da el resultado esperado.

El codigo es:

```
set test "texto....<title>texto dentro de la etiqueta</title>mas texto..."
set s [split $test "<title>"]
```

Entiendo que la lista ***s*** me deberia entregar:

```
Item 1: texto....

Item 2: texto dentro de la etiqueta</title>mas texto...
```

Pero no me realiza el "split". ¿Estaré haciendo algo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`split` se divide en caracteres, no cadenas. Transforma "<title>" en un solo caracter primero.

```
set temp [regsub -all {<title>} $test \x0]
set s [split $temp \x0]
```

Esto está traducido, no soy un hablante nativo de español.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Funciona

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que split corta por caracteres y no por cadenas y no reconoce el  igual al primer  entonces lo que recomiendo es eliminar de texto antes de split el "/" de esa forma split te funcionará bien

yo lo haría con con el split, pero la cadena a cortar se puede pretransformar con string map que puede reemplazar parejas de cadenas por ejemplo "title" se reemplaza por un simbolo como @ y en la misma linea con el split, darian los tres campos ANTES del tag,DENTRO del tag y DESPUES del Tag.

```
´set s [split [string map "{title} {\@}" $test] ">"]´
```

probé con scan y no funciona pero con esto ya funciona.

Comment: bueno esta pregunta no me deja dormir y es porque no creo que haya una forma usando comandos propios de tcl que te permitan dividir el texto como quieres,  aunque lo mejor sea que hagas un procedimiento que de una cadena string separe en tres cadenas de acuerdo a los tags html  uno que entregue el antes del tag, y otro después del tag

Comment: básicamente sería una cadena de entrada y dos de salida, una "antes" y otra "después",  y que ejecutes nuevamente esa función con la cadena de después pero cambiando el tag porque los dos tag <> y </> son diferentes y por eso no puedes hacerlo con split.